# How I start my winforms app via telnet?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, telnet

I have a windows forms application on a client machine.  I am trying to log in via telnet, shut it down, update some files, and restart it.

Using cmd on the client machine and typing in MyApp.exe works great to start it.  But if I do this in the telnet window something odd happens: The application starts in as far as it is now in the process list but none of its forms ever open nor any log4net logging is done.

What's going on and how do I fix this?

**Edit:**  This seems to be the case with all form-based windows apps. Try it out yourself: telnet localhost => notepad.  It pops up int he user interface but not the ui!

Also, I have [RAdmin](http://www.radmin.com/products/radmin/) installed on all these machines?  From what I've seen its got non-existent automation facilities but maybe there's something about it that can help me out?

Comment: The WHAT is going on is that the app is launching with no User Desktop associated with it.  You are going to need to find the currently logged in user account and run it under that users permissions.  If you run it under the telnet'd user you get a headless display - it cannot interact with the desktop in most cases.

Comment: Jason, can you please explain how to run an application as a user from telnet?  The computer only has an administrator user so i'm both telnet-ing in and running the desktop as administrator.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you can't use remote desktop?

Comment: @Jon B - then he would have to go manually log in on the kiosk again, wouldn't he?

Comment: Exactly.  I used to use remote administrator to do this, but now we've got something like 12 of these machines.  Much easier to just write a ruby script.  Or so I thought.

Comment: Ah, OK. There would certainly be other remote access options - like VNC. However, if you're automating this for a bunch of PCs, I see where you're coming from. Maybe a little client-side code would help in place of telnet.

Comment: Well yes, but I'm still not sure I understand what exactly the problem is.  Its not that the application is starting as the wrong user.  They're all Administrator and runas doesn't help.  And its not something in .net since the same thing happens to notepad

Comment: It's starting to sound like this is a limitation of telnet - you can't start a GUI app. It might be flat out impossible.

Comment: Try asking "how do you launch a GUI app using telnet" on serverfault. Maybe one of the sysadmins knows!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: In my original answer, I misunderstood your question, I thought you said you restarted the machine.

With that said, I'd still probably try to take a different approach. Can you set some type of auto update service into MyApp.exe. An easy way would be to set up a webservice which MyApp.exe can poll to see when new versions are available. Then you'll need to lauch an updater application to do the updating work.

Comment: why no user context?  I log into telnet as the user.  I do not want to restart the machine, just update the system files such as the program's dll.

Comment: Ok, we're getting into some pretty complicated architecture austronaut territory just to solve a problem with an application starting in the wrong mode.  If worst comes to worst I can do a 2 line bootstrapping app that uses Process.Start or something but that's just another moving part, there has to be something simpler?

Answer (score 1):

I think what's going on is that your app is starting up on a private desktop, and then quiting as soon as you close your telnet session.  I don't know how to make it start up on the "current/active" desktop window, but to keep it running after you log out of telnet try running with the "`start`" command.

Comment: Actually I just thought of this, if it was simply starting on a private desktop then why isn't log4net logging anything?

Comment: If you log out right away, it could be it quits before it has time to do anything.  But I suspect it's more likely a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using telnet, you could try using [VNCRobot](http://www.vncrobot.com/). I believe VNCRobot runs as the user and should share the same desktop.

Disclaimer: I've never used VNCRobot, I just thought it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds interesting but I can't justify installing more third party VNC software on these machines when we already have remote administrator running on there - even if it's automation is sh*t.

Comment: So you have http://www.radmin.com/products/radmin/ installed? I didn't notice that in the question. You might want to edit that into your question because there may be something special about telnetting via that tool that causes this problem. Or maybe not... but it's worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: Well I'm not telneting in via that tool, I'm doing this via a ruby script actually.  Or cmd, or powershell - don't particularly care which one.  I did edit this fact in however.  Maybe it has some sort of utility or extension that I could use.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP, I found a way around this limitation by using Windows task scheduler. For Windows 7, telnet is not installed by default.

I first had to change the Network Access: Sharing and security model for local accounts to "Classic – local users authenticate as themselves" by merging the following registry settings:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
"forceguest"=dword:00000000

I placed it in a file on a remote FTP server and used the FTP command to get it.

Merge it with regedit /s file.reg

Then I created a task that ran once:
SchTasks /Create /SC ONCE /RU "user" /RP pass /TN "StartApp" /TR "\"C:\Windows\NotePad.exe\"" /ST 00:00:00

Manually started the schedule:
Schtasks /run /tn "StartApp"

Deleted the schedule:
schtasks /delete /F /tn "StartAPP"

And that worked. Crazy right! What a pain!

Comment: Yikes! Sorry that you have to work with Windows XP. You should tell your clients to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run PowerShell on these machines you could use it to find the running process and kill it. the..

```
Get-Process
```

..Cmdlet will show you the running processes, you can write the logic to foreach through this list and match your application with regex directly in powershell,  I don't know Ruby but theoretically you could use it to do the same invoking the powershell commands with:

```
powershell.exe -command Get-Process
```

To kill a process its:

```
Stop-Process <processId>
Stop-Process -processname <processName>
```

Not quite sure how to start the GUI process through telnet, I don't have telnet setup on my equipment.

perhaps you can do something similar to this: http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/post/Powershell-Sudo-(sort-of)-for-Vista-UAC.aspx

Setting the verb to "runas" like in the example at that address will invoke UAC, doing this I was unable to kill the new process, however I am to kill it if I set:

```
$psi.Verb = "open"
```

Additionally you can set these attributes as well:

```
Verb                    : open
Arguments               :
CreateNoWindow          : False
EnvironmentVariables    : {processor_revision, processor_level, logonserver, systemroot...}
RedirectStandardInput   : False
RedirectStandardOutput  : False
RedirectStandardError   : False
StandardErrorEncoding   :
StandardOutputEncoding  :
UseShellExecute         : True
Verbs                   : {open, runas, runasuser}
UserName                :
Password                :
Domain                  :
LoadUserProfile         : False
FileName                : notepad.exe
WorkingDirectory        :
ErrorDialog             : False
ErrorDialogParentHandle : 0
WindowStyle             : Normal
```

Comment: The only problem that I'm having is with starting the process. Stopping it is easy - taskkill.  Also no powershell, they're touchscreen dumb-terminals so its unlikely to be approved too.